# Can we test the signed apk android app from eclipse without installing from google play store?

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase

I developed an android application for in app purchase and also published on google play store.
But i want to test the application in device without installed from google play store.
So, Is it possible to test the in-app purchase without installed from google play store.

If anyone have idea.Please reply.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Google themselves have written a guide on how to test in app billing/purchases ([Guide here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html))

You can manually install your app by "allowing installs from unknown sources" in your options and just opening the apk from the device but the billing testing would still have to go through Play Services.

There is a further limitation that for the testing you need to use a real device and not an emulator but there are perhaps ways to circumvent that restriction.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But can I test in-app purchased with the signed apk same version as published on play store?Because i am getting issue onrestore transcation even if i am able to purchased sucessfully.

Comment: The version of the app installed through the Play Store and manually on the device (if identical versions) should not perform any differently. Can you confirm that you are definitely not getting the same issue when using the app when installed through the Play Store? If there is some hook that the Play Store adds to apks, that I am unaware of, that is used for in-app purchases you should perhaps look into using a closed beta release for testing (details on this in the link in my answer). That would allow you to restrict access while still testing the Play Services framework.